# DataGridView CellBeginEdit firing just once

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

My project is a Windows Forms project and I have a DataGridView.
DataGridView has a column that is an editable CheckBoxColumn.
I'm using CellBeginEdit event to make decision the CheckBox is checked or unchecked.
There is no problem when I clicked first, but when I clicked second, third or more than once, CellBeginEdit event not firing.

Comment: How do you figure that the event is not firing? Can you share your code?

Comment: I put the breakpoint at the first line of the event method. It is not firing.

Comment: Are you navigating away to another cell after that first click?

Comment: @OhBeWise not. But after the first click, if I focus another editable cell and click again the combobox cell, event is firing

Comment: As an alternative I recommend you to use CellClick event instead of CellBeginEdit.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments you stated that you are *not* navigating to another cell after that first click.

> But after the first click, if I focus another editable cell and click again the combobox cell, event is firing

This is by design.  The `ComboBoxCell` enters Edit mode on focus. While the cell maintains focus, `CellBeginEdit` will not trigger.  You can bypass this behavior by calling [`EndEdit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158620(v=vs.110).aspx), like so:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.EndEdit();
    }
}
```